# Acceleration of a container in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, acceleration

How will accelerating a container with an ideal gas in it affect the conditions? My initial thoughts are that the ideal gas will collect at the opposite end of acceleration, which means that the volume drops. According to the formula $PV = nRT$, either the pressure or the temperature would have to raise as well. Firstly, which quantity would rise if I just squeezed a gas in normal conditions? I don't see how I can differentiate between squeezing isothermally and squeezing isobarically, so would they both rise? 
Upon further thought however, we are already experiencing 9.8 metres per second squared acceleration, and that has minimal effect at low heights. So does this mean at low accelerations the afore-mentioned effect can be ignored?

Comment: Part of your problem is that the Earth's atmosphere is not a homogeneous system (the pressure and density as well as the temperature vary greatly with altitude) and the simplified assumptions of equilibrium thermodynamics do not apply without modifications. The acceleration can not be ignored. It is the effect that breaks the homogeneity assumption of thermodynamics.

Comment: But in can be ignored at low altitudes right? Nitrogen and oxygen levels don't really change all that much until i'm halfway up mount everest I think

Comment: In physics the quality of the approximation that we chose determines the quality of the solution that we get. Can we treat a small volume of Earth's atmosphere as if it were a mixture of ideal gases in an ideal container? Of course. Is that sufficient to predict the weather? No.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the atmosphere, we usually assume that the stationary atmosphere is adiabatic, that is, there is very little transferral of heat between regions of different height . Combining hydrostatic equilibrium with the adiabatic law of an ideal gas gives you a variation of temperature (and pressure) in the direction of acceleration.

Check out [Richard Fitzpatrick's notes](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/lectures/node56.html) for a good discussion.